# Openerp purchase order workflow 'confim order' action shall exit the edit mode

Tags: openerp-7, workflow-activity

I am creating the new purchase order (quotation).  While creating I click 'confirm order' before clicking.  Ideally application shall save the order and move to confirm status and exit the edit mode (to read mode).  **(Expected way)**

However, what is happening is, when I click 'confirm order' button, order will be saved and moved to confirmed status and keep the form in edit mode.  **(Wrong one)**

It looks very simple.  But I am missing some key concept.

Can some one guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the default workflow of openerp. Your order changes the state and has been saved as well but it doesn't change from edit mode.